# Re-initialising js plugin after livewire render

Tags: laravel-livewire

How do I initialise a plugin on a component after validation fails?

I have a `textarea` that line numbers gets added to via JS.

On submit, the `textarea` is then validated. If validation fails, it renders a normal `textarea`. I used the `element.initialized` hook and it worked, but only once - so basically: form is loaded and `textarea` initialised. It fails validation, and `textarea` is initialised again. Then it fails validation again, and `textarea` is the plain, vanilla textarea.

This is the text area:

```
<textarea class="border-gray-300 block w-full focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 shadow-sm rounded-none rounded-md" name="results" rows="10" wire:model.defer="unprocessedResults" id="results-textarea"></textarea>
```

This is my js:

```
document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function() {
    TLN.append_line_numbers('results-textarea');
    Livewire.hook('element.initialized', function(el, component) {
        TLN.append_line_numbers('results-textarea');
    })
});
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried with `wire:ignore` ?

Comment: Can you maybe add more context in your comment. Not sure why `wire:ignore` would work?

Answer (score 1):

The best option here would be to use `wire:ignore` or `wire:ignore.self` on that element. That would mean that Livewire will not touch that element when it does its DOM-diffing. This means, that other JavaScript libraries will remain in their state, if they are manipulating the DOM themselves.

```html
<textarea
    class="border-gray-300 block w-full focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 shadow-sm rounded-none rounded-md"
    name="results"
    rows="10"
    wire:ignore
    wire:model="unprocessedResults"
    id="results-textarea"></textarea>
```

- https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#ignoring-dom-changes